# Not receiving result from stored procedure MSSQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hi i have a issue where i am not receiving the result from stored procedure, im using php and mssql database.

I can see the query in the sql server profiler, and when i run that query in sql server management tool, the query works properly.

When i use the query with php i get the following error

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -28 [code] => -28 [2] => The active result for the query contains no fields. [message] => The active result for the query contains no fields. ))`

Here is my php code 
         'if ($this->conn) {

```
        $session_id = "9999912C8D74";
        $patient_id = "9999912C8D74";
        $days = 7;

        $params = array (
                array (
                        $session_id,
                        SQLSRV_PARAM_IN 
                ),
                array (
                        $patient_id,
                        SQLSRV_PARAM_IN 
                ),
                array (
                        $days,
                        SQLSRV_PARAM_IN 
                ) 
        );

        $tsql_callSP = "exec dbo.STOREDPROCEDURECALL @SessId=?, @PatId=?, @days=?";

        $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query ( $this->conn, $tsql_callSP, $params );

        if ($stmt3 === false) 

        {
            echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";

            die ( print_r ( sqlsrv_errors (), true ) );
        }

        if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt3 ) === false) 
        {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        $name = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt3, 1);
        echo "$name: ";

        $comment = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt3, 2);
        echo $comment;

        while ( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object ( $stmt3 ) ) {
            var_dump ( $obj );
            echo $obj->BGUM . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

I have tried a magnitude of solutions on stackoverflow, nothing has worked :-(, any suggestion would be gratefully appreicated. Thank you.

Comment: What your SP should return? One value, or table?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply it should return a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, the answer was in adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in SP.

Remove this part:

```
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt3 ) === false) 
    {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $name = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt3, 1);
    echo "$name: ";

    $comment = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt3, 2);
    echo $comment;

    while ( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object ( $stmt3 ) ) {
        var_dump ( $obj );
        echo $obj->BGUM . "<br>";
    }
```

And change it like this with the help of `sqlsrv_fetch_array` (read about [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)):

```
while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
    echo $obj[0]." ".$obj[1]."<br>"; //I don't know how many columns your SP return
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);
```

Or you can fetch with column names:

```
while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $obj['name']." ".$obj['comment']."<br>"; 
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);
```

Comment: still getting the follwoing array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(5) "IMSSP" ["SQLSTATE"]=> string(5) "IMSSP" [1]=> int(-28) ["code"]=> int(-28) [2]=> string(51) "The active result for the query contains no fields." ["message"]=> string(51) "The active result for the query contains no fields." } }

Comment: Than take this string `exec dbo.STOREDPROCEDURECALL @SessId='9999912C8D74', @PatId='9999912C8D74', @days=7` and execute in SSMS. What will be in output?

Comment: No change sorry to say,  no table data coming through.... the error is related to this if (sqlsrv_fetch ( $stmt3 ) === false)

Comment: Just changed that to the new solution, its returning nothing(blank screen),  no errors either.. im getting a blank screen, i checked http status code and it is 200. so no problem with the code.

Comment: And how about SSMS? did you try execute this query directly?

Comment: !! Just realize your params array maybe the problem...  try like this  `$params = array ($session_id, $patient_id, $days);`

Comment: i had tried that previously and again just now.. still no change i just did the follwoing var_dump(sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)); that returned bool(false)

Comment: This is the query in SSMS which returns the correct data .. exec sp_executesql N'exec dbo.USP_Return_STOREDPROCEDURE @SesId=@P1, @PattId=@P2, @days=@P3',N'@P1 varchar(36),@P2 varchar(36),@P3 int','912C8D74','912C8D74',7

Comment: Strange, just tested, with and without `SQLSRV_PARAM_IN` all works fine. Your SP returns only one resultset?

Comment: yes, i just tested the code with a simple select query and that works too, so im guessing the problem must be in the php SP query

Comment: Maybe `@pattId`? In your query one `t` in comments `tt`. Try to remove `@SessId=?, @PatId=?, @days=?` and add `?, ?, ?`

Comment: :) give it a try with `?, ?, ?` and do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in the beginning of your SP?

Comment: changed to $query = "exec dbo.USP_Return_STOREDPROCEDURE ?, ?, ?";  still no luck

Comment: should i have SET NOCOUNT ON, ?

Comment: It may help. If no - try execute your query with the help of `sp_executesql`. I have no more ideas

Comment: I just put it on and changed the queries, still no luck.. thank you very much for your time and effort gratefully appreciated . if you have any ideas later drop us a comment. thank you :-)

Comment: For sure will! Check for misspellings in exec query, there also may be a problem.

Comment: I got it working by adding set nocount on. Thank you gofr1 :-)

Comment: I just wrote the comment to question what it was :) I will add this to my answer, so other could use it if they need :) Great!